# How to disable line wrapping in the WebStorm console?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Line wrapping in the WebStorm console currently is making readability worse for some logging messages.

In Settings > [Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-console-folding.html) I see you can enable a disable soft-wrap. This is not what I want.

Does anyone know if you can disable line wrapping?

Comment: could you clarify what console is meant? is it about the built-in terminal, or some particular run console?

Comment: Hi @lena yep I mean the built-in terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, please vote for [IDEA-212620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212620) to be notified on any progress with this feature request